# Java Jackson Large Object Serialization Optimization

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I am using Jackson to serialize large objects about hundreds of other objects in it. This comes with the performance problems.

Most of the custom Serialization class is same as "AmountAsStringSerializer" in the "JSONSerializer" class and all defined static.

There is an array of object in my (T object) that increases processing time. When it has 40 element in it, this lasts 25 seconds and over 70 element, it lasts nearly 3 min and goes on like that.

I know other serialization 3rd party APIs but the system is very heavy so that we can't migrate to them for now. I need solution for Jackson. **Does anyone know how to improve this Jackson Serialization process?**

There you can see my implementation:

```
public class JSONSerializer {

   private static ObjectMapper mapper = null;

   static {
       mapper = new ObjectMapper();
       addModule(mapper);
       configure(mapper);
   }

   public static <T> String serializeObject(T object) {
       String str= null;

       try {
           str = writer.writeValueAsString(object);
       } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
       } 

       return str;
   }


   private static void addModule(ObjectMapper om) {
       SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("ModuleName", new Version(1, 0, 0, null, "", ""));

       module.addSerializer(new AmountAsStringSerializer());
       //and nearly one hundred serializer module 
       //.
       //.
   }

    private static void configure(ObjectMapper om) {
       om.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
       om.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
       om.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES, false);
    }


    static class AmountAsStringSerializer extends StdSerializer<Amount> {
         protected AmountAsStringSerializer() {
             super(Amount.class);
         }

         @Override
         public void serialize(Amount value, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException, JsonGenerationException {

              jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
              if (value != null && value.getContent() != null) {
                   jsonGenerator.writeStringField("content", value.getContent().toString());
              } 
              else {
                   jsonGenerator.writeNull();
              }

              jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();

         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Kryo serializer library that is specifically designed to be very fast and efficient.

This is the [link](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo) to official repository on GitHub and [here](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo/wiki/Documentation-for-Kryo-version-1.x) the documentation.

Comment: I know the Kryo but the system is very heavy so that we can't migrate to Kryo for now. Kryo doesn't work for me. If you have the solution for jackson serialization that's ok but not this.

Comment: Ops...sorry! I haven't understand this from your question. I haven't the solution in that case.